# Hiding files from the nemo file manager

Tags: linux, privacy

I recently switched from windows to linux. I have sensitive images inside my linux mint os and I was wondering if I can hide it from the nemo file manager.

Comment: Files or directories with a leading dot are commonly not shown by default. This is not a real protection though since they can easily be displayed, for example by toggling display of hidden files in nemo with Ctrl+H. So you are asking only for (trivial to break) obscurity, not actual security.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are two ways to hide files in nemo

1. any file or folder whose name starts with a `.` is hidden (e.g. `.config` is an hidden folder, among many others, in your home directory)
2. create a text file called `.hidden` inside the folder. In this file put the name of the files and holders you want to hide, one per line.

However, as Steffen has already pointed out in his comment, this does not provide any protection whatsoever, as any program or command can still see these files. If you want to hide sensitive files, the only good solution is to create an encrypted partition on your disk